# How to update a property according clicked MenuItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, contextmenu

I am generating a MenuItem according the values of an enumeration and I would like to update a property with the content of the clicked menu item.

This works perfectly with a ComboBox :

[image]

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TimelineUnitValues}}" SelectedItem="{Binding TimelineUnit}" />
```

But with a MenuItem that seems an impossible mission since it doesn't have a `SelectedItem` property.

Generating the menu works fine but updating it with a behavior does not do anything, even though the behavior do receive the value it just doesn't update the target property.

[image]

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource TimelineUnitValues}}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                        <ei:ChangePropertyAction Changed="Freezable_OnChanged"
                                                    PropertyName="TimelineUnit"
                                                    TargetName="UserControl1"
                                                    Value="{Binding Path=.,
                                                                    Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

Actually I can't think of any other mechanism than using `ChangePropertyAction`.

(I am looking for a XAML-only solution)

Do you know how I can achieve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said you are looking for XAML-only solution, but this involves only tiny bit of code.

First, drop your ItemTemplate and use Style instead:

```
<ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.MyCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"/>
        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
    </Style>
</ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
```

Then add simple command in VM:

```
this.MyCommand = new DelegateCommand<MyEnum>(val => TimelineUnit = val);
```

I tested it with DevExpress DelegateCommand, but similar implementations of ICommand should work as well.

Comment: That's mostly what I did, ended up hooking to a simple Click handler :D Note, I think I know why it wouldn't update the property -> ContextMenu are detached from the visual tree, while it doesn't make any error, it silently fails ...

Comment: Yeah, the thing is I've spent about 45 minutes on it for no result, it ain't worth it !